# Change iPhone volume without user interaction, is it possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, volume

I've seen this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215524/how-do-you-set-the-hardware-volume-in-an-iphone-app) but this is only useful if I wanted the user to pick the volume himself. I wanted my application to change the volume gradually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465733/setting-iphone-to-vibrate-and-setting-iphone-back-to-sound-via-app/1466904#1466904)

You have to remember that the iPhone is designed as phone first and a computer second. Since phones are emergency communication devices whose functioning can literally be a matter of life and death, any programing functionality that might interfere with phone function is restricted. If a program could override the hardware volume settings it could cause a user to miss a critical call with possibly disastrous consequences. No app needs volume control more than users need their phone.

You can always adjust the output of your app's own sound. The `AVAudioPlayer` for example has a volume setting. You just can't control the volume of the hardware and other apps.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/volume) to play your sounds, you can just set the **volume** property.

If you are using [AudioServicesPlaySystemSound](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlaySystemSound), then you cant.