# iOS Simulator Sound

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

Is there a way to tell the iOS simulator which audio device connected to your computer you want it to use?

The simulator seems to pick whatever audio device is last connected to your machine.  I've got a USB audio device (fasttrack pro) I use for my main sound playback and then a USB headset I use for my skype calls.  More often than not, the simulator's audio is played on the headset instead of my  main speakers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I found that both the input and output device much match in system sound settings.  Often I have them set to different devices.  If they don't match, the simulator seems to default to  the last connected audio device selected among the input and output devices.

Comment: That's true, I don't know why they don't allow us to choose a device for it. I had to quit and reopen the simulator to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

On a related note: if you're like me and don't like interface sounds and therefore uncheck the preference "Play user interface sound effects" (Sound > Sound Effects), you'll need to check it to get sound out of the simulator.

Comment: this would have taken me forever to find.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt the simulator has a setting for that, but you can set the main output device in System Preferences > Sound.

Comment: yeah i know how to change my main output device but simulator dosent respect that.

Comment: Oh really? Well you should maybe say that in the question. However, I'm fairly certain there's no way to do it. I mean, there's only so many menus in the program...

Comment: I was really wondering if there was a hidden preference I could change on the command line.  I know all the simulator menu's quite well.

Comment: Ah. Well again, I still doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will fix your issue, but it fixed mine.

I wanted the iOS simulator to output sound through a device I had connected and not the internal speakers.  When I select the System Prefs Sound and selected my device as output, it would not work.

So, I selected the Sound Effects tab from the Prefs - Sound window and selected my device under Play Sound effects Through   and presto it worked.

Don't know the in-outs of iphone sound, but apparently mine were being treated as sound effects.

Hope that helps,  if not,  I gave it a shot.

Comment: Thanks Rick.  I've had the sound effects output set to the m-audio fast track pro audio device too and still get the problem.

Comment: This works.  I was using system sound APIs on the iOS device and it looks like those are indeed routed through the system sounds.

Comment: This worked for me, but it also rerouted my Spotify music to that speaker which I wasn't wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Open iOS Simulator, under Hardware toolbar you can control Audio Input, Audio Output, and volume as well!
I think it was added at Xcode 9.2, and that it's available only when running simulator with iOS 11 and above

Answer (score 0):

```
func vibratePhone() {
    if (UIDevice.current.model == "iPhone") {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1352)
    } else {
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(1105)
    }
}
```

1352 Is the system sound ID for Vibration and 1105 is for Tock.caf if the user's device is an iPad or an iPod Tock.caf will be played in place of vibration.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I tried all the solutions and nothing worked. Until I found the "silent switch" of the simulator and unmuted the phone and the sound started working!

Answer (score -1):

Working on an audio project on my studio and still didn't got it working on MOTU Hardware with everything pointing to the interface! All system sounds route properly except the iOS Sim!

Did this workaround:

iOS Sim/OS X -> SoundFlower virtual I/O -> (Any audio program like Logic/Live) -> MOTU HW

This might give you the freedom to route your audio as you please ;)