# Not getting sound from iOS simulator

Tags: ipad, cordova, ios-simulator, mp3

I have a Cordova (phonegap) app that is playing mp3 audio files but I can not hear it in the simulator.  Not getting any error message at all.  Sound does play in browser and I checked all the System Preference settings according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772112/ios-simulator-sound).  Anyone else experience this?