# How to turn off audio in MPMoviePlayerController iPhone

Tags: iphone

How to turn off & turn on audio of MPMoviePlayerController. I tried useApplicationAudioSession this property even though it is not working. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 12):

Never too late to answer right? Was looking for a way to do it as well and it took me a while to find the right links.

First please note `useApplicationAudioSession` is now (iOS 6) deprecated

Setting the ambient audio session will prevent stopping audo in other apps

Set this somewhere in your code:

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];`

Here's the doc
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html

Here's the explanation
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

In my case setting the category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add to this discussion here in 2016 to say that muting audio this way still works in Xcode 8. Note that I use NSUserDefaults to keep track of whether the user has switched on the side switch or not:

```
    // Mute audio depending on side switch state
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"RINGER_IS_ON"]) {
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil]; // Ignore the side swicth - play audio
    } else {
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil]; // Respect the side switch - don't play audio
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the last line

```
useApplicationAudioSession
```

A Boolean value that indicates whether the movie player should use the application’s audio session.

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL useApplicationAudioSession
```

**Discussion**

> The default value of this property is
>   YES. Setting this property to NO
>   causes the movie player to use a
>   system-supplied audio session with a
>   nonmixable playback category.
>
> **Important: In iOS 3.1 and earlier, a movie player always uses a
>   system-supplied audio session. To
>   obtain that same behavior in iOS 3.2
>   and newer, you must set this
>   property’s value to NO.**
>
> When this property is YES, the movie
>   player shares the application’s audio
>   session. This give you control over
>   how the movie player content interacts
>   with your audio and with audio from
>   other applications, such as the iPod.
>   For important guidance on using this
>   feature, see “Working with Movies and
>   iPod Music” in Audio Session
>   Programming Guide.
>
> **Changing the value of this property
>   does not affect the currently playing
>   movie. For the new setting to take
>   effect, you must stop playback and
>   then start it again.**

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:(use a value between 0.0 and 1.0)]
```

If your `MPMoviePlayerController` uses the application audio session, this should adjust the volume. But be careful in using this.. It is a work around

Comment: I am using IOS 4.2 and videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
  [videoPlayer moviePlayer].useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
  
  [self.viewVideo addSubview:videoPlayer.view]; Please advice where i am wrong.

Comment: Setting this property to NO causes the movie player to use a system-supplied audio session with a nonmixable playback category.

Comment: If you want you can go through http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW2

Comment: I set both property even though volume is not changing. [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0.0];
  [videoPlayer moviePlayer].useApplicationAudioSession = NO;

Comment: If you want to use `[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0.0];` you must set `[videoPlayer moviePlayer].useApplicationAudioSession = YES;`

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I have worked as you guide, but i didn't get result as i request. Can you please provide workable code snippet for this or any reference site?

Comment: Your solution solve the video freezing problem but now the sound is stopped when video is playing... Any idea why ? I'm using a AVAudioPlayer